# Calculate polynomial using LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, polynomials

As a part of a LINQ tutorial I have the following exersise:

> You're required to calculate the value of an nth-degree polynomial.
> The arguments of the function are:
>
> -**int x** - the value of x for the polynomial
>
> -**IEnumerable coeffs** - the polynomial coefficients
>
> Example:
>
> -Input: 2, [3,4,5]
>
> -Output: 25 (calculated as `3*2^2+4*2+5`)
>
> Hint: you may need the overload of **Aggregate()** that takes a seed
> value. You may also need to introduce a separate variable for tracking
> the index of the element you're processing.

Any ideas?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? Finding N? Looping through the coefficients? Calculating the sum?

Comment: Do you understand what `Aggregate` does? Are you familiar with [Horner's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method)?

Answer (score 1):

As simple as that:

```
public static int Poly(int x, IEnumerable<int> coeffs)
{
    int idx = 0;
    return coeffs.Reverse().Aggregate(0, (p, q) => p + q * (int)Math.Pow(x, idx++));
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First of all weird choice of IEnumerable coefficients. You could rewrite the below code to "subtract" rather than add to the current coefficient's rank, I guess that's what is expected by whoever designed the problem, since that would require using the overload which takes a seed value, since the first term's value would no longer be coefficient * x^0 (or simply coefficient) in that case. I just think this version is easier to follow and explain, and you should try writing the answer as expected based on this:

```
IEnumerable<int> coefficients = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 }.Reverse(); //we reverse the coefficients' order for simplicity, in real cases this might not be possible, since IEnumerable does not guarantee it is "replayable"
int x = 2;
int rank = 1; //we start from rank 1 since the first value is x^0 * coefficient, so it's already "added" in Aggregate and correct, we don't need to use the "seed value overload"
var polynomialValue = coefficients.Aggregate((sofar, current) =>
            {
                //we just need to worry about calculating the current value
                int currentValue = current * (int)Math.Pow(x, rank); //you could replace this with a for if you want or use Aggregate here as well, I was just lazy
                Console.WriteLine($"Adding {current} * {x}^{rank} = {currentValue}");
                rank++;

                //and returning the aggregated result which is what we calculated so far plus the current term
                return sofar + currentValue;
            });
```